# Using zip() to rotate a list

Tags: python, list

I have a set of records coming back from the database in the following form:

```
data = [
    ["date", "value1a", "value2a", "value3a", ...],
    ["date", "value1b", "value2b", "value3b", ...]
]
```

I want to turn that set of rows into a list like

```
[
    [("date", "value1a"), ("date", "value1b"), ... ],
    [("date", "value2a"), ("date", "value2b"), ... ]
]
```

I know `zip()` does this sort of thing, but I'm not clear on how to get the date into each record (and make them tuples). The length of the rows coming back from the database will not always be the same, but I will know the expected length in each call.

Comment: Where are the separate lists/values coming from? Where is `value1b` located in your original list?

Comment: Is there only one date, as you example result implies?

Comment: Yes, the first column is the date, the rest of the row is data that needs to be paired with the date.

Comment: "Where is value1b located in your original list?" - sorry this wasn't clear: it's the corresponding result in the second row of the data set. I'll update the question.

Comment: @Tom What would make your questions more clear in future is give actual values you could pass into Python. It makes testing code easier, and it makes your explanation clearer. Here, for example, you are missing the outer list surrounding your lists, and your values are not real values in Python (use strings instead of pretend variable names, and use `...` instead of `etc.`. I have made an edit to show you what is desirable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data = [["date_a", "1a", "2a", "3a"], 
        ["date_b", "1b", "2b", "3b"]]

print zip(*(zip(itertools.repeat(ls[0]), ls[1:]) for ls in data))
```

gives

```
[(('date_a', '1a'), ('date_b', '1b')),
 (('date_a', '2a'), ('date_b', '2b')),
 (('date_a', '3a'), ('date_b', '3b'))]
```

See comments for some useful variations.

Comment: +1. This is the best solution for the updated question. Note that under 2.x, you would be better off using [`itertools.izip()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) to avoid computing the lists first.

Comment: @Lattyware Better to leave that as a note since the current answer is cross-compatible.

Comment: If you are using Python 3 you can do this which is a lot more readable imo: `zip(*(zip(itertools.repeat(k), v) for k,*v in data))`

Answer (score 2):

Use itertools repeat for the first element:

```
zip(itertools.repeat(ls[0]), ls[1:])
```

Comment: This doesn't produce the requested output.

Comment: With `ls = ["date", "value1a", "value2a", "value3a"]`, `list(zip(itertools.repeat(ls[0]), ls[1:]))` gives me `[('date', 'value1a'), ('date', 'value2a'), ('date', 'value3a')]` which seems to be correct as far as I can tell.

Comment: @recursive The asker wants all of the `1` values grouped, not all of the `a` values grouped.

Answer (score 2):

Edit: This was based off the original question under the presumption that the data would be in a single list, not multiple input lists. The edit to the question has made it clear that this is not the case, so I would advise you follow [Janne Karila's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10691255/722121).

Presuming that you know how many different values there are, this is a good solution, using `itertools`' [`grouper()` recipe](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
import itertools

def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
     args = [iter(iterable)] * n
     return itertools.zip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

data = ["date", "1a", "2a", "3a", "1b", "2b", "3b", "1c", "2c", "3c"]
first = data.pop(0)
print([list(zip(itertools.repeat(first), items)) for items in zip(*grouper(3, data))])
```

Gives us:

```
[
    [('date', '1a'), ('date', '1b'), ('date', '1c')], 
    [('date', '2a'), ('date', '2b'), ('date', '2c')], 
    [('date', '3a'), ('date', '3b'), ('date', '3c')]
]
```

Note that this will pad the lists with `None`s if there are not enough values.

Naturally, you can use [a generator comprehension instead of a list comprehension](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t85uBptTDYY) if just want to loop over it, for example, not display it. E.g:

```
(zip(itertools.repeat(first), items) for items in zip(*grouper(3, data)))
```

Note that I am using Python 3.x, so under 2.x, wherever I use `zip()` you probably want `itertools.izip()`, and `itertools.zip_longest()` becomes `itertools.izip_longest()`.

Note that the better way of doing this - presuming that you know what *defines* a value that should be in the first list, what should be in the second list, etc...

```
import itertools
import operator

data = ["date", "1a", "2a", "3a", "1b", "2b", "3b", "1c", "2c", "3c"]
first = data.pop(0)

print([list(zip(itertools.repeat(first), items)) for _, items in itertools.groupby(sorted(data), operator.itemgetter(0))])
```

Which produces:

```
[
    [('date', '1a'), ('date', '1b'), ('date', '1c')], 
    [('date', '2a'), ('date', '2b'), ('date', '2c')], 
    [('date', '3a'), ('date', '3b'), ('date', '3c')]
]
```

Naturally, this only works for the given example, presuming your real data is different, you will want to change `operator.itemgetter(0)` to a function that defines which list your item should be grouped into.

Note it might we worth encapsulating off our prefixing work:

```
def prefix(iterable, prefix):
    """Returns every element of an iterable prefixed with a given value."""
    #prefix("ABCDEFG", "x") --> ("x", "A"), ("x", "B"), ("x", "C"), ("x", "D"), ...
    return zip(itertools.repeat(prefix), iterable)
```

And we then have simply:

```
(prefix(items, first) for items in zip(*grouper(3, data)))
```

and

```
(prefix(items, first) for _, items in itertools.groupby(sorted(data), operator.itemgetter(0)))
```

Which are far more readable.

Answer (score 0):

This can also be achieved with a simple list comprehension technique

```
data = [    ["date1", "value1a1", "value2a1", "value3a1"],
            ["date2", "value1b2", "value2b2", "value3b2"]
       ]
result = map(list, zip(*[[(x[0], x[i]) for x in data] for i in range(1,len(x))]))

[
  [('date1', 'value1a1'), ('date1', 'value2a1'), ('date1', 'value3a1')],
  [('date2', 'value1b2'), ('date2', 'value2b2'), ('date2', 'value3b2')]
]
```